# Многократная смена цвета фона блока по клику на кнопку

Tags: jquery

Возникла небольшая проблемка - при нажатии на кнопку, меняется цвет блока, но меняется всего лишь раз и на один цвет. По тз нужна кнопка, которая меняет цвет с каждым кликом, но при этом цвета должны быть разными. Как все это воспроизвести в реальности? Спасибо!
Пример кода прилагаю:

```js
//первая кнопка
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button-1').click(function() {
    $('.main-content-1').css('background-color', 'blue');
  });
});

//вторая кнопка 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button-2').click(function() {
    $('.main-content-2').css('background-color', 'green');
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  color: #302E2D;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  padding: 30px 60px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}

.main-content-1 {
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 17%;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-content-2 {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

footer {
  padding: 30px 60px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

#button-1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#button-2 {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>Шапка</header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="main-content-1">
        <p>dfgs sregsre gse sgsr gsrg srg sr gsfg fdg </p>
      </div>
      <div class="main-content-2">
        <p> fhgdohgoesh od uth iodo ood do doood oo dijtoid h toh doi dotoi ho ohoh oih o
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div id="button-1">
      Click on me
    </div>
    <div id="button-2">
      Click on me again
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самым простым способом, будет генерации случайного числа, с помощью `Math.random()`, и последующим его использованием, в качестве значения оттенка, в цветовой модели HSL(оттенок, насыщенность, яркость):

```js
//первая кнопка
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button-1').click(function() {
    $('.main-content-1').css('background-color', `hsl(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 170) * 2},100%,50%)`);
  });
});

//вторая кнопка 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button-2').click(function() {
    $('.main-content-2').css('background-color', `hsl(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 340)},100%,50%)`);
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  color: #302E2D;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  padding: 30px 60px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}

.main-content-1 {
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 17%;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-content-2 {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

footer {
  padding: 30px 60px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

#button-1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#button-2 {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>Шапка</header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="main-content-1">
        <p>dfgs sregsre gse sgsr gsrg srg sr gsfg fdg </p>
      </div>
      <div class="main-content-2">
        <p> fhgdohgoesh od uth iodo ood do doood oo dijtoid h toh doi dotoi ho ohoh oih o
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div id="button-1">
      Click on me
    </div>
    <div id="button-2">
      Click on me again
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!)